# Should Abstract Relationships be used in Symfony or normal ORM relationships be used?

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, symfony

I am rewriting a web application that was coded by another programmer in cakePHP years ago and the programmer did not design his database to have foreign key restraints. I'll quickly explain the flaw the cakePHP system has.

- The "products" table has a field named "type" which can be "normal" or "cpa". (Don't worry about what CPA stands for, not important)
- "normal" products generate a tracking id in the "tracking" table each time they are visited in a browser. "cpa" types generate a tracking id in the "cpatrack" table each time they are visited.
- (Here is the issue) When a product is purchased, an entry is made in the "sales" table and in the sales table there is a field named "track_id". If the product type was "normal" the ID from the "tracking" table is stored in "track_id". If the product was "cpa" the ID from the "cpatrack" table is stored in "track_id".

If I setup Symfony correctly and create proper relationships, I can't have the "track_id" field refer to more than one entity obviously so I am at a point where I need to make a decision. I have looked into Abstract Relationships on the Symfony documentation and it mostly applies to keeping bundles from having dependencies but it could also allow me to choose the correct entity when doing something like

```
$track = $sale->getTrackingId();
```

Should I look into doing the Abstract Relationships to help solve this issue OR should I just create another field in the sales table such as "cpa_track_id" and use normal relationships? Any advice?

Comment: I definitely would go for the 2d, with the first you'll lose most/all the benefits of Doctrine/ORM

Answer (score 0):

You can't use abstract relationships for that. Abstract relationships are a tool to decouple bundles from each other, however you have to decide what entity class a relationship points to at implementation time when using the bundle with the abstract relationship in it in an application. You can't decide at runtime which class it points to on a row by row basis.

If you can make changes to the database schema, have a look at [class table inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance). Just as a rough sketch:

- create new table `tracking_hdr` with columns `id` and `type` ("cpa" or "normal") and matching inheritance mapping (`tracking` and `cpatrack` are the child entity tables)
- assuming your `tracking_id` is a *signed* integer (which it often is since many people don't bother to add the `UNSIGNED`...) and all existing values are positive, multiply all ids in the `cpatrack` table by -1 to prevent collisions with the `tracking` table
- `INSERT INTO tracking_hdr (id, type) SELECT id, 'normal' FROM tracking;`
- `INSERT INTO tracking_hdr (id, type) SELECT id, 'cpa' FROM cpatrack;`
- update the `sales` table to negate `tracking_id` where the associated product is a "cpa" product
- create foreign key on `sales` table pointing to `tracking_hdr`

This way, the changes to the database schema are relatively minor, especially read-only accesses from the old cakephp code should still work. You should however keep in mind that class table inheritance might have a performance impact since it easily leads to quite complex `JOIN` queries if you are not careful.

If you can't make any changes to the schema, I think you are out of luck and have to live with option 1, `getTrackingId()`.